# What is causing the "XConnect Exception Filter OnException()" errors in xconnect log files?

Tags: xconnect

I see errors like *XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - "https://xconnect/refdata/definitiontype/ensure"* in the xconnect log files. What is causing those errors and does it mean something is configured wrong?

These can be seen after opening the home page of the Storefront.

```
2019-05-23 09:49:31.586 +02:00 [Information] XConnect Test Host Application Start, Machine: "7CFA130A43F3", Site: "xconnect", AppId: "/LM/W3SVC/928776700/ROOT"
2019-05-23 09:49:32.930 +02:00 [Information] Certificate Validation Filter Enabled, Thumbprint: 3CB4DA6F75DC4A297D08FFBEDCFC4DBCC0167331
2019-05-23 09:49:32.931 +02:00 [Information] SSL Validation Filter Enabled
2019-05-23 09:49:33.998 +02:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:xconnect, Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xconnect\App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
2019-05-23 09:51:35.299 +02:00 [Information] Create "XdbContextLoggingPlugin"
2019-05-23 09:51:35.313 +02:00 [Information] Register "XdbContextLoggingPlugin"
2019-05-23 09:51:35.442 +02:00 [Error] XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - "https://xconnect/odata/DeviceProfiles?%24filter=Id+eq+21a018ec-4504-42e7-bfc6-f0a2b368005a"
    System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
       at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    2019-05-15 14:51:50.810 +02:00 [Error] XConnect Exception Filter OnException(), url - "https://xconnect/refdata/definitiontype/ensure"
    System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
       at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? I have a similar issue on one of our environments.

Comment: No. I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is a hard one to trace down. But Sitecore is requesting a filter in an xConnect query and that filter is breaking on xConnect. It returns these unreadable messages. But the underlying query has a filter that is bad. Like running into a null or something like that. I had contacts with no identifiers and saw errors just like this when those contact where included in my query.

Answer (score 1):

I've contacted Sitecore Support and below is their response:

> The mentioned above exception usually happens due to the fact that
>   xConnect has not responded within 5 seconds. So I believe it happened
>   due to xConnect has been restarting and its nothing to worry about.
>
> In case the exception occurs not only once after xConnect start please
>   check whether app pool user has required access rights.. For example,
>   please refer to the following article:
>   https://blog.wenstor.com/2015/05/cess-to-registry-key-global-is-denied-in-sitecore.html
>   Could you please check if providing access to the app pool user fixes
>   the errors?

Comment: Did this fix the `XConnect Exception Filter OnException()` error? I did also get an error about access to the registry key 'Global', which the linked article fixes, but I'm still getting the original error.

Comment: No I didn't make any changes as the response of Sitecore Support is stating that it can happen when xConnect is starting and its nothing to worry about.